# shell .bashrc not handling text wrapping

Tags: bash, ssh

I found a good customization to my .bashrc for my prompt to show extra information and provide color highlighting.  Here's what I have:

```
# ----- Define a few Colors
BLACK='\e[0;30m'
BLUE='\e[0;34m'
GREEN='\e[0;32m'
CYAN='\e[0;36m'
RED='\e[0;31m'
PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
BROWN='\e[0;33m'
LIGHTGRAY='\e[0;37m'
DARKGRAY='\e[1;30m'
LIGHTBLUE='\e[1;34m'
LIGHTGREEN='\e[1;32m'
LIGHTCYAN='\e[1;36m'
LIGHTRED='\e[1;31m'
LIGHTPURPLE='\e[1;35m'
YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
WHITE='\e[1;37m'

function __setprompt {
  local SSH_IP=`echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1 }'`
  local SSH2_IP=`echo $SSH2_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1 }'`
  if [ $SSH2_IP ] || [ $SSH_IP ] ; then
    local SSH_FLAG="@\h"
  fi
  PS1="$CYAN[\u$SSH_FLAG:$BROWN\w$CYAN]\\$ $NOCOLOR"
  PS2="$CYAN>$NOCOLOR "
  PS4='$CYAN+$NOCOLOR '
}
__setprompt
```

The issue I'm running into is that it doesn't handle wrapping text correctly (see below screenshot).  Can anyone offer any advice on what the problem might be?  It looks like it doesn't adjust at all what is typed in by the user.

[image: Command prompt example]

Comment: What are you using for your terminal client? It looks like it may be a problem with the terminal emulation rather than with the prompt.

Comment: I'm using Putty, but the issue only came up once I implemented this bashrc change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's the value of `CYAN` `BROWN` `NOCOLOR` vars ?
You most problably forgot to wrap them in `\[` and `\]`,
to mark them as *non-printing* characters.

if your `CYAN` is

```
CYAN="\e[0;36m"
```

you need to wrap it in `\[` and `\]`, like

```
CYAN="\[\e[0;36m\]"
```

---

otherwise, wrap the vars themselves in the prompt variables, like

```
PS2="\[$CYAN\]>\[$NOCOLOR\] "
```

see the comments here:

```
function __setprompt {
  local SSH_IP="${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"      # no need for echo/awk/sed
  local SSH2_IP="${SSH2_CLIENT%% *}"    # use parameter expansion instead
  if [[ -n "$SSH2_IP" || -n "$SSH_IP" ]]; then  # bash uses double brakets
    local SSH_FLAG="@\h"                        # and the OR operator works inside
  fi
  PS1="\[$CYAN\][\u$SSH_FLAG:\[$BROWN\]\w\[$CYAN\]]\\$ \[$NOCOLOR\]"  # dont mess with [ and ]
  PS2="\[$CYAN\]>\[$NOCOLOR\] "                                       # only wrap color vars in \[ and \]
  PS4="\[$CYAN\]+\[$NOCOLOR\] "                 # single quotes will not expand $vars
}
__setprompt
```

---

also, have a look at `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable,

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>     If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

and also note that by convension capital variable names are kept to be used by the environment

Comment: I've added my colors on in the original post... I also found these colors on the web.  It looks like they're lacking a trailing `]`.  What do the `[``]` signify?  How come it still works with one piece missing?

Comment: no, `[` and `]` is good, you need to wrap every color variable in `\[` and `\]`, see my updated answer